# Is the address of a local variable always guaranteed to be valid

Tags: c, pointers

I came across a warning in my compiler: "address will never be NULL"
The code looks like:

```
struct mydata * var = NULL;
/* some function which may modify var*/
if(NULL != &var) {
    // do something
}
```

The actual warning (-Werror flagged):

`error: the comparison will always evaluate as 'true' for the address of 'var' will never be NULL [-Werror=address]`

So does this mean that address of a local variable is always non-NULL ? It was a typo to compare it with `&var`.

Comment: Of course. When the variable is declared it must have an address that points to its value.

Comment: I believe `var` can be `NULL`; `&var` (the address of the local pointer variable), can not (unless optimized out, as said below. But that wouldn't happen if you use the variable in a comparison, right?). Perhaps you meant to compare `if(NULL != var)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use it yes, it will always have a valid address.

If you don't use it, it will probably be optimized or ignored by the compiler. So this address will have no value, but you will never know it.

Comment: Just to note, "using it" would include taking the address of the variable.

Comment: I see a good analogy of your answer with quantum super-positioning :)

Answer (score 1):

> #### C 2011 Section 6.3.2.3 Paragraph 3
>
> An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type **`void *`**, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> #### C 2011 Footnote 66
>
> The macro `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as a null pointer constant

Therefore, a null pointer never points to a valid object.